# issue in web-socket php

Tags: php, websocket, phpwebsocket

I have used `WebSocket` in `PHP`. but somehow it will close after some time(so many requests).

Is it anyway to handle it?

We got following error when we try to run it after stop:

> socket_bind(): unable to bind address [10013]: An attempt was made to
>   access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
>        in C:\wamp64\www\Websocket\server.php on line 52
>
> Warning: socket_listen(): unable to listen on socket [10022]: An invalid argument was supplied.
>    in C:\wamp64\www\Websocket\server.php on line 55

Here is my code:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//include 'Triangulate.php';

$filename = 'logs.txt';

class Values
{
    public $distance;
    public $rasp_id;
    public $rssi;
}

$host = '10.37.54.167'; //host
$port = '9000'; //port
$null = null; //null var


$rasp = array(
    47 => array(17, 0),
    124 => array(1,6.4),
    43 => array(1,0),
    44 => array(4.6,2));

//Create TCP/IP sream socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
//reuseable port
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

//bind socket to specified host
socket_bind($socket, 0, $port);

//listen to port
socket_listen($socket);

//create & add listning socket to the list
$clients = array($socket);
$distance = array();
$totalbicken = array(array());
//start endless loop, so that our script doesn't stop
while (true) {
    //manage multipal connections
    $changed = $clients;
    //returns the socket resources in $changed array
    socket_select($changed, $null, $null, 0, 10);
    $fp = fopen($filename, 'a+');
    //check for new socket
    if (in_array($socket, $changed)) {
        $socket_new = socket_accept($socket); //accpet new socket
        $clients[] = $socket_new; //add socket to client array
        $header = socket_read($socket_new, 1024); //read data sent by the socket
        perform_handshaking($header, $socket_new, $host, $port); //perform websocket handshake
        socket_getpeername($socket_new, $ip); //get ip address of connected socket
        $response = mask(json_encode(array('type' => 'system', 'message' => $ip . ' connected'))); //prepare json data
        fwrite ($fp,$response . "\n");
      //  send_message($response); //notify all users about new connection
        // send_message_socket($response, $socket_new);
        //make room for new socket
        $found_socket = array_search($socket, $changed);
        unset($changed[$found_socket]);
    }

    //loop through all connected sockets
    foreach ($changed as $changed_socket) {
        //check for any incomming data
        try {
            while (socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 1024, 0) >= 1) {
                $received_text = unmask($buf); //Unmask Recive data.
                fwrite ($fp,"Text receive:" . $received_text . "\n");
                $tst_msg = json_decode($received_text); //json decode.
                fwrite ($fp,"Json Decord!". "\n");
                if (!isset($tst_msg->action)) {
                } else {
                    $user_action = $tst_msg->action; //sender name.
                    if ($user_action == "distance") { //If action is distance.
                        $rasp_id = $tst_msg->rasp_id; //get raspberry uniq id.
                        $beacon_id = $tst_msg->beacon_id; //get beacon id
                        $distance_temp = $tst_msg->distance; // get distance
                        $rssi = $tst_msg->rssi; //get RSSI.

                    fwrite ($fp,isset($distance[$beacon_id]). "\n");

                       fwrite ($fp,"Get all values!". "\n");
                        // echo mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'action'=>'distance', 'beacon_id'=>$beacon_id, 'rasp_id'=>$rasp_id, 'distance'=>$distance)));

                        if (isset($distance[$beacon_id])) {
                            $totalbicken[$beacon_id] = count($distance[$beacon_id]); //get total distance of sender beacon
                        } else {
                            $totalbicken[$beacon_id] = 0;
                        }
                        if (isset($rasp[$rasp_id])) {
                            echo "\nRequest from: " . $rasp_id;
                            $myVal = new Values();
                            $myVal->distance = $distance_temp;
                            $myVal->rasp_id = $rasp_id;
                            $myVal->rssi = $rssi;
                            $flag = false;
                            if (isset($distance[$beacon_id])) {
                                if (count($distance[$beacon_id]) > 0) {
                                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($distance[$beacon_id]); $i++) {
                                        $myTempVal = $distance[$beacon_id][$i];
                                        if (($myTempVal->rasp_id) == $rasp_id) {
                                            $flag = true;
                                            $distance[$beacon_id][$i] = $myVal;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (!$flag) {
                                        $distance[$beacon_id][$totalbicken[$beacon_id]] = $myVal;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    $distance[$beacon_id][$totalbicken[$beacon_id]] = $myVal;
                                }
                            } else {
                                $distance[$beacon_id][$totalbicken[$beacon_id]] = $myVal;
                            }

                            if (count($distance[$beacon_id]) > 2) {
                                /*$data = triangulate($rasp[$distance[$beacon_id][0]->rasp_id], $distance[$beacon_id][0]->distance,
                                $rasp[$distance[$beacon_id][1]->rasp_id], $distance[$beacon_id][1]->distance,
                                $rasp[$distance[$beacon_id][2]->rasp_id], $distance[$beacon_id][2]->distance);*/
                                fwrite ($fp,"Before Triangulation!". "\n");
                                $data = getTrilateration($rasp[$distance[$beacon_id][0]->rasp_id], $distance[$beacon_id][0]->distance,
                                    $rasp[$distance[$beacon_id][1]->rasp_id], $distance[$beacon_id][1]->distance,
                                    $rasp[$distance[$beacon_id][2]->rasp_id], $distance[$beacon_id][2]->distance);
                                fwrite ($fp,"End Triangulation!". "\n");
                                $response_text = mask(json_encode(array('type' => 'message', 'action' => 'distance',
                                'beacon_id' => $beacon_id, 'distance' => $distance[$beacon_id], 'coordinates' => $data)));
                                fwrite ($fp,"Response: ". $response_text . "\n");
                                send_message($response_text);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    fwrite ($fp,"Break!: ". "\n");
                    break 2; //exist this loop*/
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            fwrite ($fp,"Exception:  done! \n");
            fwrite ($fp,"Exception: ". $e->getMessage(). "\n");
            echo "Exception:" . $e->getMessage();
        }

        $buf = @socket_read($changed_socket, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
        if ($buf === false) { // check disconnected client
            // remove client for $clients array
            try {
                $found_socket = array_search($changed_socket, $clients);
                socket_getpeername($changed_socket, $ip);
                unset($clients[$found_socket]);
                //notify all users about disconnected connection
                $response = mask(json_encode(array('type' => 'system', 'message' => $ip . ' disconnected')));
                send_message($response);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "Exception:" . $e;
            }
        }
    }
}
// close the listening socket
socket_close($socket);
$fclose ($fp);

function send_message($msg)
{
    global $clients;
    foreach ($clients as $changed_socket) {
        @socket_write($changed_socket, $msg, strlen($msg));
    }
    return true;
}
function send_message_socket($msg, $changed_socket)
{
    @socket_write($changed_socket, $msg, strlen($msg));
    return true;
}

//Unmask incoming framed message
function unmask($text)
{
    $length = ord($text[1]) & 127;
    if ($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($text, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 8);
    } elseif ($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($text, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 14);
    } else {
        $masks = substr($text, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 6);
    }
    $text = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i % 4];
    }
    return $text;
}

//Encode message for transfer to client.
function mask($text)
{
    $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
    $length = strlen($text);

    if ($length <= 125) {
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    } elseif ($length > 125 && $length < 65536) {
        $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
    } elseif ($length >= 65536) {
        $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
    }

    return $header . $text;
}
//handshake new client.
function perform_handshaking($receved_header, $client_conn, $host, $port)
{
    $headers = array();
    $lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $receved_header);
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $line = chop($line);
        if (preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches)) {
            $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
        }
    }
    $secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
    $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
    //hand shaking header
    $upgrade = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
        "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
        "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
        "WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n" .
        "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$port/Websocket/shout.php\r\n" .
        "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
    socket_write($client_conn, $upgrade, strlen($upgrade));
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: would be nice to see the code related to the errors, maybe ?

Comment: @AymDev: thanks for the reply. Please have a look into the question for the code. I have updated my question with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have setup Linux environment and test. It is working fine. It might a firewall issue in windows.

As per my knowledge, the newer version of windows (after service pack-3) has some of the RPC rules for connection (Limit of HTTP requests and connection in second) so, that might be an issue.

Please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/windows-firewall/create-an-inbound-icmp-rule).

As of now, change the operating system is the one of a solution.

Thanks & Regards
Jignesh M. Mehta